TimeoutException received when trying to print an element - Python Selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

chrome_options = Options()
service = Service(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

driver.get('https://app.itsdispatch.com/dispatch.php')

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "email")))

email_input = driver.find_element(By.ID, "email")
email_input.send_keys('emails')

password_input = driver.find_element(By.ID, "password")
password_input.send_keys('Pass')
time.sleep(5)
go_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class, 'mdl-button--accent')]")
go_button.click()

time.sleep(5)
header =  driver.find_element(By.ID, "dboard-title")
time.sleep(4)
print(header.text)
driver.quit()

Error:
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
Stacktrace:

Trying to print that element

Can you edit your question and share the HTML of the page after you login? i.e. the page which loads up after you click on GO button. Without this we'll not be able to help you. Please read How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Since your error here is TimeoutException, is it possible that driver.find_element did not find the id=dboard-title element? Note that selenium's driver.find_element can be set to wait implicitly
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
# Set the implicit wait time to 10 seconds
driver.implicitly_wait(10)  
element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "element_id")

After implicit waiting is set, driver.find_element repeatedly tries to find the element for the specified amount of time until it is found or the wait time runs out.
